# Sass failing to compile - Web Essentials 2013 Update 4 "Unable to find resource"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

Does anybody have an idea, what causes the following error?

```
23.07.2015 17:48:14: SCSS: Compiling widgetmain.scss
23.07.2015 17:48:14: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:14: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:15: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:15: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:15: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:16: Looking for resource @ http://localhost.:55559/
23.07.2015 17:48:16: Unable to find resource, aborting
```

It occurs when I save a scss file. It occurs even when I clear the file completely. That's why I did not post any source code. The port number changes every time.

When I open the compiled view of the file it shows:

```
/*
Compilation Error occurred (see error list to navigate to the error location):
*/
```

I already reinstalled Web Essentials, but I had no luck.

Comment: I am seeing the same 'Looking for resource..' messages after I installed VS 2013 Update 5. Maybe not related Web Essentials as I am seeing them after successful build.

Comment: Version 2.6.12 in VS 2013 ultimate won't compile scss to css #1914 https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1914 has 2.6.13 download on the last. I've tried it, but still can't solve this problem. You may give it a try.

Comment: 2.6.13 did not solve the problem. I now installed 2.5.4, because my colleagues are using it as well.

Comment: According to https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1914 , fix had been merged in https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/1927 . The next release should include the fix...

Comment: With the latest update (2.6.36), this problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1914 @efepuntomarcos's information, I add "localhost." (that has a dot at the end) into the proxy ignore list in IE, that also fix this problem and maintains IE's function.

Comment: With the latest update (2.6.36), this workaround is not needed any more. You can delete it from IE's proxy ignore list.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Solution:

1. Open up your command prompt and try to ping localhost. (with dot at the end).
2. If you can ping localhost. you can go ahead an open up your system control. Type 'proxy' into the search box and click on 'configure proxyserver'.
3. Go to the tab 'Connections' -> Lan-Properties -> uncheck everything and press Ok.

PS.: If you can't ping localhost. you have another problem. Try to fix that first (like fixing your host file).

Try to compile now. This solution worked for me.
Hope it helps.